# Can call Hugging Face Inference Endpoint using Apache HttpClient but not Retrofit

Tags: retrofit2, apache-httpclient-4.x, huggingface

As explained in this [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3908), I deployed an Hugging Face model as Inference Endpoint (gpt2 to be more specific).

I am able to call the endpoint using Apache `HttpClient` but if I use Retrofit I get a `HTTP 400 Bad Request` error. I inspected the generated requests and they look identical. Code output, showing HTTP requests and responses, is shown below.

```
---[Apache HtttpClient with URL: https://by62y2zqbeqalfay.eu-west-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud]------------
POST https://by62y2zqbeqalfay.eu-west-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer public-endpoint-no-key-needed
Content-Type: application/json
[Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 30,Chunked: false]
{"inputs":["Alan Turing was"]}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
---------------
[ [ {
  "generated_text" : "Alan Turing was born in Germany on May 11, 1928. He went into physics at Oxford University in 1874. His work for four years at the Department of Mathematics helped to establish the mathematics at Oxford in 1894. In 1926 he had the same"
} ] ]
---------------
---[Retrofit 2 with URL: https://by62y2zqbeqalfay.eu-west-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud]------------
POST https://by62y2zqbeqalfay.eu-west-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud/  ???
Authorization: Bearer public-endpoint-no-key-needed
Content-Type: application/json
[Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 30] false false
{"inputs":["Alan Turing was"]}
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
```

As the code is a bit long and have some dependencies, I created a [Git repo](https://github.com/mzattera/stackoverflowquestion) with the full Eclipse project. Below some code snippets where I call HttpClient and Retrofit, respectively.

```java
// Apache HttpClient code

    String INFERENCE_ENDPOINT = "https://by62y2zqbeqalfay.eu-west-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud";
    ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        JSON_MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        JSON_MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        JSON_MAPPER.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE);

        System.out.println("---[Apache HtttpClient with URL: " + INFERENCE_ENDPOINT + "]------------");

        try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {

            final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(INFERENCE_ENDPOINT + "/");

            httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + API_KEY);
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            TextGenerationRequest req = new TextGenerationRequest();
            req.inputs.add("Alan Turing was");
            String json = JSON_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(req);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));

            System.out.println(httpPost.getRequestLine().toString());
            for (Header h : httpPost.getAllHeaders()) {
                System.out.println(h.toString());
            }
            System.out.println(httpPost.getEntity().toString());
            System.out.println(new String(httpPost.getEntity().getContent().readAllBytes()));

            HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = resp.getStatusLine();
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            System.out.println(statusLine);
            System.out.println("---------------");
            Object obj = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(responseBody, Object.class);
            System.out.println(JSON_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj));
            System.out.println("---------------");
        }
```

```java
// Retrofit code

    ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        JSON_MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        JSON_MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        JSON_MAPPER.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE);
    }

    // API request object (will be serialized as JSON)
    public static class TextGenerationRequest {
        public List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // API response object (will be de-serialized from JSON)
    public static class TextGenerationResponse {
        public String generatedText;
    }

    // API to call HF
    public static interface HuggingFaceApi {
        @POST
        Single<List<List<TextGenerationResponse>>> textGeneration(@Url String url, @Body TextGenerationRequest req);
    }

    // Client to call HF
    public final static class HuggingFaceClient {

        private final static String API_BASE_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/";

        private final HuggingFaceApi api;

        private final OkHttpClient client;

        public HuggingFaceClient() {

            client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                    .readTimeout(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            return chain.proceed(
                                    chain.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Test2.API_KEY)
                                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json").build());
                        }
                    }).addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request req = chain.request();
                            System.out.println(req.method() + " " + req.url() + "  ???");
                            for (String h : req.headers().names()) {
                                System.out.println(h + ": " + req.headers().get(h));
                            }
                            System.out.println("[Content-Type: " + req.body().contentType().toString()
                                    + ",Content-Length: " + req.body().contentLength() + "]");
                            System.out.println(req.body().isDuplex() + " " + req.body().isOneShot());

                            final Request copy = req.newBuilder().build();
                            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                            copy.body().writeTo(buffer);
                            System.out.println(buffer.readUtf8());

                            return chain.proceed(req);
                        }
                    }).build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_BASE_URL).client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(Test2.JSON_MAPPER))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).build();

            api = retrofit.create(HuggingFaceApi.class);
        }

        // Only method API exposes
        public String textGeneration(String url, TextGenerationRequest req) {
            return callApi(api.textGeneration(url, req)).get(0).get(0).generatedText;
        }

        private <T> T callApi(Single<T> apiCall) {
            try {
                return apiCall.blockingGet();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                if (e.getCause() != null) {
                    System.out.println("Error caused by:");
                    e.getCause().printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void testHRetrofit(String url) {
        System.out.println("---[Retrofit 2 with URL: " + url + "]------------");

        HuggingFaceClient cli = new HuggingFaceClient();

        TextGenerationRequest req = new TextGenerationRequest();
        req.inputs.add("Alan Turing was");

        String resp = cli.textGeneration(url, req);
        System.out.println(resp);
        System.out.println("---------------");
    }
```